# Replace shut off valve under kitchen sink

Tags: valve

I would like to request the information to replace the typical 2 shut off valves with thread connection, one for cold water, the other one for hot water(see in the following picture) that located  under the kitchen sink faucet and that keeps freezing, stuck, can not turn it to shut or open. Due to my hearing problems, I could not take your call, so please text me instead,  It has not been leaking so far, so it is NOT an emergency situation. Does anyone how to loose it？ It is so tight and rusty.

Comment: do you want to replace it or just turn off a stubborn valve? You don't need to turn it off to replace it...

Comment: Pictures or a better description of your plumbing would help.

Comment: Your pic did not appear.